# Compare 2 columns values (in the same row)

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I need a macro that filters rows which values for columns A and B are equal, or which is the same, which difference is 0.

Normally I apply autofilter for a single range, like this:

`ActiveSheet.Range("A2:AX2").AutoFilter Field:=Range("X" & 1).Column, Criteria1:=">0"`

In this case I want to match or compare 2 columns and apply a filter when `A-B=0`

Of course I could add another column to be the difference between these 2, but if I can I prefer to avoid it.

PS: Later, I will need another filter for `A-B-C=0`, in case your solution fits this one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible filtering with `AutoFilter` by using a criteria, where one field must match another field, without using a helper field (column). Surely it is possible using a multiple fields filter but then for each field a criteria must be set and a criteria cannot be a formula which refers to the same row in the table for example.

The only thing I could think is using conditional formats and then filtering by colors.

Example:

[image]

```
Sub Makro1()

 sConditionalFormula = "=AND($A1<>"""",$B1<>"""",$A1=$B1)"
 'FormatConditions needs localized formulas, so we create such:
 Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Formula = sConditionalFormula
 sConditionalFormulaLocal = Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).FormulaLocal
 Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count).Clear

 With ActiveSheet

  With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
   .FormatConditions.Delete
   .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=sConditionalFormulaLocal
   With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
    With .Interior
     .Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End With
   End With

   .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor

  End With

 End With

End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just add a second line specifying column and criteria to the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx).

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'if there is an active AutoFilter, turn it off
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=0
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=0

        'filtered on rows that have zero in column A and column B

        .AutoFilter field:=1
        .AutoFilter field:=2

        'filter is active but no criteria has been applied

        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=0
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=0
        .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=0

        'filtered on rows that have zero in column A, column B and column C

    End With
    'turn off AutoFilter completely
    If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: tbh, I'm a little concerned that hte OP's code starts the .AutoFilter in row 2. While the column header labels may very well be in row 2, I've also seen people code .AutoFilter incorrectly and only include the data portion when .AutoFilter **requires** a row of column header labels. The [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx) have have to be shifted down a row to be absolutely correct.

Comment: the importance of including a snippet of the spreadsheet layout/example date.

Comment: @Jeeped that's right, my heading are at row 2. Actually, watching the code, I see this finds 0 in columns A and B (or A, B and C) but what I need is to find same vale in both columns